# How to insert array values in mysql with a loop

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Reading a Textarea with jquery , splitting each line in Array then with ajax posting that array in mysql through php but in results only first value inserted.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS addresses ( 
    id int(8) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    user_id int(8) DEFAULT NULL, 
    address_value varchar(100) NOT NULL 
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Here is Jquery Code :

```
$('#insertad').click(function(){
    var lines = $('#txtArea').val().split('\n');

    var phparray = new Object();

    for(var i = 0;i < lines.length;i++){
        phparray[i] = lines[i]; //store value in object
    }
    $.post('functions.php?action=insertad', {array1:$.param(phparray)}, function(resp){
        $('.text-success').html(resp);  
        if(resp == 'Added'){

        $('.text-success').html('Added Address :');

    }   
    }); 

});
```

Here is PHP Code :

```
if ($action == 'insertad') {
    $pieces   = explode('&', $_POST['array1']); //explode passed serialized object
    $phparray = array();
    foreach ($pieces as $piece) {
        list($key, $value) = explode('=', $piece);
        $phparray[$key] = $value; //make php array
    }

    $length = count($phparray);

    for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++) {

        $sql     = "select address_value from addresses where address_value = '$phparray[$i]'";
        $qry     = mysql_query($sql);
        $numrows = mysql_num_rows($qry);
        if ($numrows > 0) {
            echo "One Found !!" ;
        } else {
            $sql = "insert into addresses (address_value) values ('$phparray[$i]')";
            $qry = mysql_query($sql);
            if ($qry) {
                echo "Added";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `mysql_*` is deprecated and closed in php 7 and your code is open for SQL injection read this http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: What is your php version??

Comment: you have the structure of mysql table...I don't understand how your table is  structured. Second use some debugging and check if your array is posted to the php file entirely.

Comment: `$sql     = "select address_value from addresses where address_value = '$phparray[$i]'";` the array is between single quotes, php interprets it as a string...

Comment: PHP version: 5.4.45

Comment: **CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `addresses` (
  `id` int(8) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  `user_id` int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address_value` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1; **

Answer (score 0):

Try this please...

**JS:**

```
var $textarea = $('textarea'); // maybe you have to specific your selector!
var textArray = $textarea.val().split("\n"); // this array is already done, your have not todo next for() loop

$.post('functions.php', {
    action: 'insertad', 
    array1: textArray
}, function(results) {
  $.each(results, function(reslt) {
    if(result === 'Added') {
      $('.status').append(result);
    }
    else {
        $('.status').append(result);
    }
  });       
});
```

**PHP:**

```
if($action === 'insertad') {
    $results = [];
    $input = $_POST['array1'];

    foreach($input AS $textLine) {

        $escapedTextLine = mysqli_real_escape_string($resource, $textLine);

        $result = mysqli_query($resource, 'select address_value from addresses where address_value = "'.$escapedTextLine.'"');
        $affectedRows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if($affectedRows > 0) {
            $results[] = 'One Found !!';
        }
        else {
            $result = mysqli_query($resource, 'INSERT INTO `adresses` (`address_value`) VALUES("'.$escapedTextLine .'");

            if($result) {
                results[] = 'Added!';
            }

        }
    }

   return $results; // we return all done results to check this array in ajax response
}
```

**Notice:** I wrote the code blind, so maybe you have to make some small changes for e.g. your variables or something like that.

**Notice 2:** I write the code with `mysqli`, so you have to rewrite your Database connection setup code.

Please never forget to use `mysqli_real_escape_string` do something with user contents.